# UDp Broadcast packets not received by the server

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, datagram

I am creating a basic android application that sends a broadcast message. In my laptop I have a server listening to all broadcast messages. But the package is never recieved and i don't know why(If I sent it to the specific Server ip, the servers gets the packet) . Here is my code for  both, the application and the server.

Server:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int port = 8063;
        DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        dsocket.setBroadcast(true);
        
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,
                            buffer.length);
                        
                        
       while (true) 
        {
             System.out.println("Receiving...");
             dsocket.receive(packet);
             System.out.println("received...");
             String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
             System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName()
                                    + ": " + msg);
             packet.setLength(buffer.length);
         }
```

Application:

```
socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.setBroadcast(true);

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[]{0,1,2,3},4,
            InetAddress.getByName("172.16.255.255"), 8063);
socket.send(packet);
```

Any advice on why the server is not receiving the package?

Edit:

It seems the University network is blocking broadcast packages, we tried it with 4g and it worked fine.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast can only reach nodes within the same [broadcast domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain), while unicast, as in your second example, is IP-routed, so unless your client and server machines are wired into the same switch/hub, or explicitly put into the same VLAN, broadcast will not work for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Both application and server are wired into the same broadcast direction.                                   We tried it with 4G doing the same procedure (both app and computer connected to the 4g) and it worked. So the only possible answer is that the university wifi does not allow those types of messages...                                              We tried to implement jmdns but it seems to fail with android, do you know other alternatives besides Bluetooth to discover the pc IP from the application?